# Is it possible to overload click method in Selenium with java for various element locators

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to overload helper methods for clicking element based on the locator type such as xpath, id, css etc.

I have written code like this

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ById;

public class AutomationHelper {

```
public static void clickElement(By xpath){

}
public static void clickElement(By Id){

}
```

}

I would like to call method from my test class like this

AutomationHelper.clickElement(Id);
AutomationHelper.clickElement(Xpath); etc.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**No**

Overloading is for sending distinct combinations of *data types* (one `int`, or one `String`, or and `int` and a `String`) to a single method, but what you're doing is sending the same *data type* with different values and think it will be treated differently; somehow inferring metadata.

Also in your examples, you're only sending the *By*, but you're not sending any sort of path. So, you're letting the method know to interpret something as an xpath or as a CSS string, but you're not actually sending the something.

But I think what is really in your head is that you're hoping that by sending a string of some kind of pathing, the metadata will somehow let the method know what to do with it.

You need to either create multiple methods:

```
public static void clickElementByXpath(String path) {}
public static void clickElementByCss(String path) {}
```

or one method with more arguments:

```
public static void clickElement(String by, String path) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need overloads to do this. You can use

```
public static void clickElement(By locator)
{
    driver.findElement(locator).click();
}
```

You can use it with any locator type, e.g.

```
By someButton = By.id("buttonId");
By someLink = By.linkText("myLink");
By someDiv = By.xpath("//div[.='containedText']");
```

and call it like

```
clickElement(someButton);
clickElement(someLink);
clickElement(someDiv);
```